# Chat Application written with node js, angular js, and socket.io not working across pcs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I've got two questions actually, I used a tutorial to build a simple chat application using angular js, node js, and socket.io. 
it runs perfectly across browsers on the same pc but it doesn't seem to work across different pcs

1. How to make this work across pcs
2. How to get this application running on a live web server.

Comment: *"How to get this application running on a live web server"* ...that is simply too broad a question for this site. You need to sign up for a hosting service to do. There are numerous free services even you can use

Comment: @charlietfl i have a hosting service already, I thought running apps like a chat app that uses socket.io isnt possible with regular web hosting plans

Comment: why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @charlietfl for instance, i have to run a server.js using node before sent messages are seen on browsers. I dont know if this would be a criteria as well on the web server, if yes, i have no idea how this is done there.

Comment: really not clear what problem is if you are already using a node host

Comment: I use Azure for my websites - note that you need to enable websockets as they are turned off by default for web apps. This may be the case for other hosting solutions as well

Answer (score 0):

1) Make it work across different computers by deploying your application to a host, instead of using localhost.

2) Follow one of many tutorials from the world wide web to deploy your application. DigitalOcean have an excellent one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @Tom, I managed to host the app online using  heroku The steps there are quite doable for persons at juvenile levels.
For Number 1, I'm still unaware how to do the pc-to-pc communication offline, Can you explain or point me to a resource on how i'd deploy an app on a host asides localhost, and get other computers connected to this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. pc to pc offline is impossible for obvious reasons, other lan through a LAN which has nothing to do with a web application. Please learn more about web application architecture and come back.

Comment: if the answers to questions are so obvious especially to inquisitive learners like myself venture into new territories like this, then there'd be no need for stackoverflow, but then again, thanks

Comment: Please learn more about the purpose of stackoverflow and how the community expects questions to be asked. You can refer to this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask